# Как сделать так, что бы при сужении браузера сайт не сужался.

Tags: веб-программирование, html, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, Как сделать так, что бы при сужении браузера сайт не сужался оставался при фиксированных размерах (как пример если сужать браузер где открыт ХешКод, то все остается на месте и ни чего ни куда не перелазиет), гугл не помог (или я не так вопрос ему поставил), вообщем помогите, или подскажите ссылку на источник если таковой имеется, заранее благодарен.

Comment: Фиксированные размеры либо размеры в пропорциях от размера экрана ( с помощью JS ) - не оно?

Comment: Фиксированные размеры body, как уже написал @timka_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если как в hashcode то можно использовать css свойство width c процентными значениями или просто свойство [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp). Вы, наверное, не заметили, но сайт сужается, правда только до определенного предела (полоса прокрутки в браузере появляется, когда окно становится уже текстового содержимого

Answer (score 0):

min-height, но с ним нужно аккуратно в ie.

Comment: ну за, что Бог, создал людей которые создали Ослика!??!

Comment: Вообще-то, Ослик был передовым браузером в своё время, и тягаться с его возможностями тогда никто не мог.И ещё 1 момент, Ослик держит свои позиции на протяжении 10 или более лет, если я не ошибаюсь, и люди его до сих пор используют)Хотя... тут тоже есть свои нюансы )

Comment: Используют... Чтобы скачать другой браузер например)))

Comment: Я думал, что автор про ширину)).

Comment: Про другой браузер зачёт :D!А автор да... про ширину.Стоп флуд товарищи. :)